# '83 Mercedes 300D will not start when warm

Tags: starting, diesel, mercedes-benz

The car runs great when first started, great pickup, etc. However, if I stop and shut off the engine, it will not start back up. At times I can pump the accelerator 5 or 6 times and then it will start if I keep my foot off the pedal, but not always. Any suggestions?

The glow plugs are good, I've recently adjusted the valves, filters all replaced, linkages replaced, turbo working properly. The first symptom was the car having no power or losing power on hills, but that is no longer the problem with the mentioned fixes. Just over 200K on the odometer. Another recent change is that I'm not driving the vehicle as much.

Comment: I presume by not start you mean the engine turns but never fires? And TD - Turbo Diesel?

Comment: 300TD is the model number of the N/A diesel station wagon. Clarification would be useful.

Comment: 300D Turbo Diesel 4-door sedan - not the station wagon. Yes, engine turns but will not fire.

Comment: 300TDT is the wagon, 300TD is the sedan IIRC

Comment: Hey I was wondering if you ever solved this problem. My 300TD has been doing the exact same thing.

Comment: I believe this must be a temperature sensor issue...an easy fix. There is one for the glow plugs and a few others. I have the same problem and that is where I am going to start.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a lack of fuel getting to the engine.

Get it hot, turn it off pull a fuel line and crank the engine, see if any diesel comes out. It could be a fuel line softening up when it gets warm and pinching shut due to the suction from the pump. If thats the case, replace your fuel lines with proper diesel rated lines.

Comment: Another easier thing you can check, is when it wont start, open the gas cap, if there is a woosh of incoming air and then the car starts, your tank is not venting and is probably a bad cap. ($10)

Answer (score 1):

agreed that this seems like a fuel problem. the easiest and most important things to check are the two fuel filters, one big, one small - replace them. it's also possible to have a clog in the strainer back at the tank.